# User::all show relationship items

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I Laravel 5.5 I am returning users information like this...

```
$users = User::all();

return Response::json(array(
    'error' => false,
    'response' => $users,
));
```

I have a belongs to many categories relationship setup and would like to also show all of the categories each user belongs to.

Anyone have an example I can see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`with()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) method to load categories for each user:

```
$users = User::with('categories')->get();
```

If you don't need to load all the columns from the `categories` table, use `select()` inside the [`with()` closure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads). Also, since you're using Laravel 5.5 you could use `Resource` classes for formatting JSON.

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for.  Thanks you!